# Место для "уже" и "бы"

Tags: грамотная-речь

И второй мой вопрос.
Я с тем же примером про "половину десятого". Довольно часто задумываюсь над местом в предложении "уже" и "бы". Вроде как, русский язык не запрещает ставить их произвольно, например: "была уже половина десятого..." или "уже была половина десятого...". И соответственно: "Я бы вернулся в половине десятого", либо "Я вернулся бы в половине десятого". А бывает и так, что в рамках одного предложения частица БЫ встречается вообще несколько раз, например: "Я бы вернулся в половине десятого, если бы ты заказал мне такси". Нормально это? Или есть возможность избежать повторов частицы бы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, такие предложения встречаются. В классике сотни примеров. У Льва Толстого их чрезмерно. И конечно, следует стремиться убирать избыточность, ограничиваясь одним "бы". В вашем примере можно обойтись банальным причастным оборотом: "Заказав такси, я бы вернулся в половине десятого". Либо вообще обойтись без "бы": "Заказав такси, я мог вернуться в половине десятого".